# How call a Torch .lua file given new/different arguments?

Tags: lua, parameter-passing, torch

Suppose I have the followings in `test.lua` file:

```
require 'torch'
-- parse command line arguments
if not opt then
   print '==> processing options'
   cmd = torch.CmdLine()
   cmd:text()
   cmd:text('SVHN Model Definition')
   cmd:text()
   cmd:text('Options:')
   cmd:option('-model', 'convnet', 'type of model to construct: linear | mlp | convnet')
   cmd:option('-visualize', 1, 'visualize input data and weights during training')
   cmd:text()
   opt = cmd:parse(arg or {})
end

if opt.visualuze == 0 then 

-- Do something
```

Now assume I want to call `test.lua` given some **different** arguments through another lua file `execute.lua`:

```
dofile ('test.lua -visualize 0') --Gives an error
```

However, I am getting an error which indicates that the file 'test.lua -visualize 0' cannot be found when trying to call the function through `execute.lua`.

So, how can I correctly run another lua file which contains torch code through another .lua file?

Comment: what error? `dofile` does not accept commandline arguments. If you want to call some "file", there are functions and `loadfile` for that.

Comment: The error indicates that the file 'test.lua -visualize 0' cannot be found.

Comment: And why it is not in the question? Still the other part of my comment applies. You should use functions.

Comment: @Jakuje Sorry had forgotten to do so. It's part of the question now.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to use the variables defined inside your 'test.lua', you can use os.execute:

```
os.execute("th test.lua -visiualize 0")
```